# ignoring whitespace/newline in regex within AS3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to write a regex expression that will take this phrase

```
[[32, 120], x1y1, [object pieceP1], null]
```

and ultimately I need it to break everything apart so that the final output ends up as

```
32
120
x1y1
[object pieceP1]
null
```

now I go this phrase which is kind of close to what I want

```
var re3:RegExp = / , | \ [ | \ ] /s;
```

however my final result with this is

```
32
 120

 x1y1

object pieceP1

 null
```

As you can see, i'm getting a ton of empty lines and white space... how can I modify my expression so that these empty lines and white space are removed? I read that having x at the end of the expression would work but this didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [filter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#filter%28%29) your results after splitting. I've altered your RegExp slightly

```
var str:String = "[[32, 120], x1y1, [object pieceP1], null]";
var bits:Array = str.split(/[\[\],]+\s?/).filter( function( x ) { return !!x });

// ["32", "120", "x1y1", "object pieceP1", "null"]
```

Comment: fantastic, that is very useful! If I could upvote you I would haha, but I guess I can't for now.